# $(x-a)^2(x-a-1) + p \equiv 0 \bmod{p^3}$

Tags: number-theory

Let p be a prime and a belong to Z. Find all solutions to the equation 
$$(x-a)^2(x-a-1) + p \equiv 0 \bmod{p^3}$$

I'm having a hard time working with this as such few variables are given. We know p is prime and a is an integer, and we are solving for x. I tried letting another variable $y=x-a$, but that leaves me with $$y^2(y-1)=p(kp^2-1)$$ which tells me that either $p|y$ or $p|(y-1)$, but not much about the possible values of x... I'm uncertain whether it is looking for a set of numbers (and whether that set would be dependent on a and p? I couldn't imagine it not be), or if the answer is no solution. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $p \|(x-a)^2(x-a-1)$, so $p \nmid x-a$ and $p \| x-a-1$. Write $x-a=rp+1$, where $p \nmid r$. We have $(rp+1)^2rp+p \equiv 0 \pmod{p^3}$, so $0 \equiv (rp+1)^2r+1 \equiv 2r^2p+(r+1) \pmod{p^2}$. Thus $p \mid r+1$. Write $r=sp-1$. We have $2(sp-1)^2p+sp \equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$, so $0 \equiv 2(sp-1)^2+s \equiv 2+s \pmod{p}$. Therefore we can write $s=tp-2$.

We now have $x=a+rp+1=a+(sp-1)p+1=a+((tp-2)p-1)p+1=tp^3-2p^2-p+(a+1)$, where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. In other words, $x \equiv -2p^2-p+(a+1) \pmod{p^3}$.

Comment: How do you know p does not divide x-a?

Comment: And how are you able to chop out the p when you go from $p^3$ to $p^2$ and likewise from $p^2$ to $p$?

Comment: @AddisonEuhus If $p \mid x-a$ then $p^2 \mid (x-a)^2(x-a-1)$, which contradicts $p \| (x-a)^2(x-a-1)$. I am using the fact that $ad \equiv bd \pmod{cd}, d\not =0$ implies $a \equiv b \pmod{c}$. To see this, write $ad=bd+cdk$ for some integer $k$, then dividing by $d$ (which is not $0$) gives $a=b+ck$.

Comment: Oh I understand the reducing part now. But wait why does $p^2 | (x-a)^2(x-a-1)$ contradict p dividing it?

Comment: $p \| (x-a)^2(x-a-1)$ means that $p$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $(x-a)^2(x-a-1)$. You can see this by noting that $(x-a)^2(x-a-1)$ is $p$ less than a multiple of $p^3$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider it mod $p$.  Either $x \equiv a$ or $a+1 \mod p$.  Then write $x = a + t p$ or $x = a+1 + tp$ ...